# Can Javascript function arguments in the middle of a set of them be omitted?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Can you call a Javascript function that expects let's say five arguments, and supply let's say the first three, and the fifth, but I want the fourth argument to be absent, i.e. null or undefined.  The form of this I'd like to use would be: myfunction(1,2,3,,5);

I can't figure out if the "double commas" with nothing between them can pass thru as "null" or something like that, yet the fifth argument passes without a problem.

You can call myfunction(1,2,3) and if the function expects #4 and #5 these appear as undefined or typeof undefined, just fine.  It's an omitted one in the middle I'm having trouble with.

Thank you, stackoverflow fans!

P.s. myfunction(1,2,3,null,5); seems to work but that seems kind of hokey, how about just the paired commas?

Comment: You mean default argument for 4th param if not passed?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it.

```
function foo(a, b, c) { return a + b + c; }
foo(1,2,3)
> 6
foo(1,,3)
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
foo(1,null,3)
> 4
```

So no, you can't just do the double comma.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately double commas are not allowed and will throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invoking the method, you could use `apply` to invoke the method. That will allow you to pass the arguments as an array and will also allow you to use the kind of syntax you want.

```
function foo(a, b, c, d, e) {

}

foo.apply(foo, [1,,,,5]);
```

Here `a` will be `1`, and `e` will be `5`. All other arguments will be `undefined`.